# Pandas loop optimization

Tags: python, performance, pandas

Is there a better way (performance-wise) for doing the following loop in pandas (assuming `df` is a `DataFrame`)?

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['signal'].iloc[i] == 0:   # if the signal is negative
        if df['position'].iloc[i - 1] - 0.02 < -1:   # if the row above - 0.1 < -1 set the value of current row to -1
            df['position'].iloc[i] = -1
        else:   # if the new col value above -0.1 is > -1 then subtract 0.1 from that value
            df['position'].iloc[i] = df['position'].iloc[i - 1] - 0.02
    elif df['signal'].iloc[i] == 1:     # if the signal is positive
        if df['position'].iloc[i - 1] + 0.02 > 1:     # if the value above + 0.1 > 1 set the current row to 1
            df['position'].iloc[i] = 1
        else:   # if the row above + 0.1 < 1 then add 0.1 to the value of the current row
            df['position'].iloc[i] = df['position'].iloc[i - 1] + 0.02
```

I will be grateful for any advices because I just started going through Pandas route and, obviously, may miss something crucial.

Source CSV data:

```
Date,sp500,sp500 MA,UNRATE,UNRATE MA,signal,position
2000-01-01,,,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-02,,,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-03,102.93,95.02135,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-04,98.91,95.0599,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-05,99.08,95.11245000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-06,97.49,95.15450000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-07,103.15,95.21575000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-08,103.15,95.21575000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
2000-01-09,103.15,95.21575000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0
```

Desired output:

```
Date,sp500,sp500 MA,UNRATE,UNRATE MA,signal,position
2000-01-01,,,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.02
2000-01-02,,,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.04
2000-01-03,102.93,95.02135,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.06
2000-01-04,98.91,95.0599,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.08
2000-01-05,99.08,95.11245000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.1
2000-01-06,97.49,95.15450000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.12
2000-01-07,103.15,95.21575000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.14
2000-01-08,103.15,95.21575000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.16
2000-01-09,103.15,95.21575000000001,4.0,4.191666666666665,1,0.18
```

**Update** All the answers below (by the moment I am writing this) produce constant `position` 0.02 value which differs from my naive loop approach.
In other words I am looking for a solution which would give `0.02`, `0.04`, `0.06`, `0.08` etc for the `position` column.

Comment: if you're looping with pandas, you're almost always doing it wrong

Comment: @SuperStew yes, I had such gut feeling

Comment: at the very least, try using `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` to loop through a dataframe if you really need to.

Comment: you can use vectorized functions (ideally) to operate on whole columns or at least the `apply` method to use built in loops that have lots of optimizations built in

Comment: Can you add example of input and desired output? Something like [mcve].

Comment: @zipa added the input and the desired output.

Comment: What do you want done for the first row?  Your desired output is apparently 0.02, but every code branch refers to `df["position"].iloc[i - 1]` but that's going to be `.iloc[-1]`, which is the _last_ value in your position series, which I don't think is what's intended.

Comment: @DSM good catch. In this case it should set to 0.02

Comment: @varnie: what most people have missed is that the nth row of your output doesn't depend upon the n-1st row of your _input_, but the n-1st row of your _output_, and so can't be trivially decomposed into shifts.

Comment: @DSM, yes, exactly!

Comment: If you have a working solution which contains simple loops, create a solution which only depends on numpy arrays like @Jonas Byström did and then use a compiler like Numba or Cython. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969037/4045774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding data and example output.  First off I am pretty sure you cannot vectorize this as each calculation is dependent on the output of the previous one. So this is the best I was able to do.

Your method came in around `0.116999` seconds on my machine

This one came in around `0.0039999` seconds

Not vectorized but it gets a good speed increase since it is faster to use a list for this and adding it back to the data frame at the end.

```
def myfunc(pos_pre, signal):
    if signal == 0:  # if the signal is negative
        # if the new col value above -0.2 is > -1 then subtract 0.2 from that value
        pos = pos_pre - 0.02
        if pos < -1:  # if the row above - 0.2 < -1 set the value of current row to -1
            pos = -1

    elif signal == 1:
        # if the row above + 0.2 < 1 then add 0.2 to the value of the current row
        pos = pos_pre + 0.02
        if pos > 1:  # if the value above + 0.1 > 1 set the current row to 1
            pos = 1

    return pos


''' set first position value because you aren't technically calculating it correctly in your method since there is no 
position minus 1... IE: it will always be 0.02'''
new_pos = [0.02]

# skip index zero since there is no position 0 minus 1
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    new_pos.append(myfunc(pos_pre=new_pos[i-1], signal=df['signal'].iloc[i]))

df['position'] = new_pos
```

Output:

```
df.position
0    0.02
1    0.04
2    0.06
3    0.08
4    0.10
5    0.12
6    0.14
7    0.16
8    0.18
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a loop. Pandas specializes in vectorised operations, e.g. for `signal == 0`:

```
pos_shift = df['position'].shift() - 0.02
m1 = df['signal'] == 0
m2 = pos_shift < -1

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'position'] = -1
df['position'] = np.where(m1 & ~m2, pos_shift, df['position'])
```

You can write something similar for `signal == 1`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks amazing, but I just noticed that the results your version produces are a bit different than I have from my initial code.

Comment: @varnie that's why it'd be really handy if you [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51522976/edit) your question to include some sample input and output :)

Comment: @JonClements okay, tried to provide some input and output (updated my question).

Comment: @jpp from my tests it looks like your version produces the same `position`: 0.02 for all rows excepr the first one (the first one is `NaN`), but in my version it gets increased by 0.02 step for each row.

Comment: @varnie, To be honest, I'd focus on the logic first rather than the result. Python / Pandas (usually) does what you tell it to do :). Is there a bit you don't understand? `pd.Series.shift` will have `NaN` in the first row, sure. But you can special case that if it's a problem.

Comment: @jpp I don't get why the `position` is not increased by step for each row.

Comment: @varnie, That's a bit vague. *Which line* is troubling you? `df['position'].shift()` does what it says on the tin, it shifts everything down one row, which makes the first row `NaN`. Do you think `shift` is doing something else in my example?

Comment: The results are troubling me. I was asking about the way to generate the same results as my naive loop approach. I was not asking about generating some other results.

Comment: @varnie, Ok. Guess you should wait a while longer for a copy-paste solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yep. When looking for performance, you should always operate on the underlying numpy arrays:

```
signal = df['signal'].values
position = df['position'].values
for i in range(len(df)):
    if signal[i] == 0:
        if position[i-1]-0.02 < -1:
            position[i] = -1
        else:
            position[i] = position[i-1]-0.02
    elif signal[i] == 1:
        if position[i-1]+0.02 > 1:
            position[i] = 1
        else:
            position[i] = position[i-1]+0.02
```

You'll be surprised at the performance gain, often times 10x or more.

Comment: This still iterates in the same way the question does.  The primary benefit of operating on numpy arrays is making use of vectorized operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely better ways, but this one should work too:

```
df['previous'] = df.signal.shift()

def get_signal_value(row):
    if row.signal == 0:
        compare = row.previous - 0.02
        if compare < -1:
            return -1
        else:
            return compare
    elif row.signal == 1: 
        compare = row.previous + 0.01
        if compare > 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return compare

df['new_signal'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_signal_value(row), axis=1)
```